# Is there any advantage to joining one team over another?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have an option to join one of 3 teams. My initial thought was to join the color team I liked best, but is there any advantage to joining one team over the another? For example, do I get different rewards when leveling up or anything?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Items are equivalent. The factions are only there to separate the player base, so that people can compete / work with each other. The important things to consider are:

- What factions have your friends joined?
- What factions are dominant in the area you play in most?
- Do you prefer to play for the dominant side, or would you rather play
  for the underdog?

Worked the same way in the predecessor of Pokémon Go, Ingress. In Ingress each faction had lore, but in Go there does not seem to be any backstory whatsoever as of yet.

Edit:
Alright so there seems to be certain icons/logos for each faction that represent one of the legendary birds (**Zapdos** for Instinct, **Articuno** for Mystic, **Moltres** for Valor). Maybe in the future some change or patch will come that will do something with the birds.

Also note that when first interacting with a gym at level 5, a short description is given by each faction leader.

Instinct is basically all about the *intuition* and '**hatching**' of Pokémon.

Mystic is interested in *researching* the '**evolution**' aspect of Pokémon.

Valor is pursuing *training* and improving the '**strength**' of Pokémon.

Perhaps in the future, bonuses of some kind are given for each faction in each of these aspects. Until anything has been confirmed this is still, of course, merely conjecture.

Comment: Could you expand on what difference your friend's faction makes? In ingress for example I heard that having friends on opposite faction meant that you could do portal swapping and thus get more XP than if you just captured and held a portal. What advantages do you get for playing with friends vs against friends?

Comment: Mostly I think collective capture and levelling up of gyms as a team - with more of you, you can boost it to a higher reputation, and install more defenders.

Comment: In ingress portal swapping was actually against the TOS when done intentionally for the purpose of gaining stats. Being on a team is more beneficial since you are meant to coordinate with teammates, not enemies.

Comment: I noticed when choosing which team to join that the background images behind the representatives are silhouettes of the 3 legendary bird Pokemon from Blue/Red, I dont know yet whether team choice will affect which one you can get at some point, but I would speculate this to be likely.

Comment: @sequoiad interesting, do you perhaps have an image of that screen? When the choice was presented to me, all I could see were the silhouettes of the representatives.

Comment: I didn't screenshot it, but found it on Google [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Pokemon+go+team+choice&client=tablet-android-lenovo&prmd=sivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi88pzku-7NAhUJPhQKHZuKAO4Q_AUICCgC&biw=962&bih=601#imgrc=BV4WyRJjZFNkpM%3A)

Comment: @sequoiad I've checked a few sources on youtube, and it seems you are entirely correct. I've updated the answer based on your info, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any king of advantage or disadvantage in joining a particular team. It would only kill the fair play which the developers of the game would want the least. Joining a team show more about which legendary Pokemon you like. Each team has it's own Pokemon Mascot.

Answer (score 1):

I think its most likely just ideological and cosmetic for the time being, perhaps in a future update, I find 10k eggs fairly often, I hatch big pokemon, and my pokemon level up to be just as strong as equivalent ones on other teams..maybe not exact, because I believe there is a base stat range on pokemon you get, like I had two vaporeon that were 10 cp apart, and every level up gives over 30...so the only thing I can figure, is that the base stats had to have been different, so it could be a coincidental difference in strength regarding similar pokemon powers