# I have the feeling I get very low level Pokemons

Tags: pokemon-go

As a Yellow Team member, I've heard that we get stronger pokemons from hatching eggs, but I have the feeling that all the pokemons I find are really low for my trainer level (14 now).
I Get a bunch of <100 while some Blue Team friends have many >100 Pokemons.

Is there any kind of bug/issue? Has anyone experienced something similar? I mean, I've never seen/caught anything >340, and I have lower level friends who have caught stronger Pokemons :(

Comment: Mind explaining de DV pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Team Buffs**
People have hypothesised the following team buffs:

> - Team Instinct (yellow) - Higher CP pokemon from eggs/better eggs (eg. 10km instead of 2km)
> - Team Mystic (blue) - Higher CP from evolution
> - Team Valor (red) - Higher CP from power up

**These team buffs have not yet been proven**.
 
It is just lore/story on a screen at the moment.
See: [Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272883/is-there-any-advantage-to-joining-one-team-over-another)

**Higher CP**
Even if low CP pokemon did have something to do with team buffs it would still not matter seeing as there is **no "team buff"** for finding higher CP pokemon. **As mentioned per story/lore per team.**

**Possilbe solution**
I noticed if I stay around my house I get low level pokemon but after walking around for a bit (walk 2km towards another area) I find higher level CP pokemon and even different types.

*Note: When I get back from my walk, most of the pidgeys, ratatas and weedles around my house have higher CP. This happens alot (of course excluding the occasional low level CP of 21 or so which is 1/10 encounters) and they are usually CP 150+*

*Also note that I am level 14 nearly level 15.*

Comment: Waitaminute, nevermind, I misread

Comment: @Unionhawk what?

Comment: I thought you were saying that team bonuses *were* in fact a thing, so I pointed out in a comment that all of those answers are negatively scored, then I reread and found out that this was the opposite of what you actually meant and I think I just need more coffee this morning.

Comment: @Unionhawk haha I did type this fairly quick and it might need some proof reading but indeed the team buffs are not yet proven.

Comment: @Unionhawk I hope the edit helped?

Comment: I had also heard about better pokemons the longer you've been walking. I have a bad phone that usually forces me to close the app, meaning I have 'short' walks, maybe that has sth to do aswell?

Comment: @MarioGarcia Maybe, I have been testing this out last few days (walking at least 5 to 10km a day now). I had to restart the app a few times (really shutting it down), coincidently I would find a new pokemon but at low CP, but that is not always the case, sometimes a high CP pidgey or something or a higher level oddish. All I noticed is that the further I walked the more chances I got at higher CP (this still needs to be proven with an actual source).

Comment: Is it my imagination or is your source for team buffs an answer that has a score of -2 currently?

Comment: @chris -2? No the source leads to a question(14+)  that was asked earlier about team buffs. No one has proof

Comment: The question asks about team differences. The highest rated answers mentions the flavour differences and say that in the future they may have different buffs. The rest of the answers have scores of zero or lower and the only one that explicitly says mystic get more CP when evolving is the answer with a -2 score. It just feels that if you are going to mention speculation that it shouldn't be what you open with. I should add that if the question had mentioned these buffs it might make more sense but it doesn't so it feels like you are introducing irrelevancies into the answer...

Comment: @Chris I don't really understand what you mean? OP stated "As a Yellow Team member, I've heard that we get stronger pokemons from hatching eggs", so I thought I would first tackle that idea of that exsisting not to expect pokemon from eggs to be higher CP. The source I linked is all about team buffs/advantages. Answers in the source talk about the points I have listed here. It was more to point out that no one has proof or source  code that these advantages are in the game. How could I formulate my answer better(what should I open with)? Could you edit it?

Comment: @Kiwi: I'm so sorry, I completely missed that quote in the thing! I feel really really silly now! I might suggest phrasing it more as "people have hypothesised the following team buffs" so before you read the buffs you know that they aren't confirmed or something but otherwise I'm going to slink off into embarrassment now. :)

Comment: @Chris haha it is okay, I changed it, thanks for the tip for a better opening :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trainer level 13 and I was wondering the same thing. But from time to time I get some high CP Pokemon (like >500)

Just be patient and keep searching.